# Apply Template on line diagram with dashed lines in SPSS

Tags: spss

I created a line diagram with multiple lines with the Chart Builder in SPSS.
Within the Chart Editor I changed the line style from "color" to "dash". I saved the style as a template to apply it to further similar line charts. However the template doesn't seem to be applied, the lines are still colored and not dashed.

Is there a way to tell SPSS in the Syntax to apply a dashed line style from template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to tell SPSS inside the GPL statement that you want to use a dashed style.

So lets assume you created the following chart from the 'breakfast.sav' sample file:

```
GGRAPH 
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=BT COUNT()[name="COUNT"] 
  gender[LEVEL=NOMINAL] MISSING=LISTWISE REPORTMISSING=NO 
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE TEMPLATE = "$HOME/SPSS/linediagram.sgt". 
BEGIN GPL 
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset")) 
  DATA: BT=col(source(s), name("BT"), unit.category()) 
  DATA: COUNT=col(source(s), name("COUNT")) 
  DATA: gender=col(source(s), name("gender"), unit.category()) 
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("Buttered toast")) 
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Percent")) 
  GUIDE: legend(aesthetic(aesthetic.color.interior), label("Gender")) 
  SCALE: linear(dim(2), include(0)) 
  SCALE: cat(aesthetic(aesthetic.color.interior), include("1", "2")) 
  ELEMENT: line(position(summary.percent(BT*COUNT, 
           base.aesthetic(aesthetic(aesthetic.color.interior)))), 
           color.interior(gender), missing.wings()) 
END GPL.
```

Now within the `ELEMENT` statement you need to change both `color.interior` functions into `shape.interior`. So the statement would look like this.

```
  ELEMENT: line(position(summary.percent(BT*COUNT, 
           base.aesthetic(aesthetic(aesthetic.shape.interior)))), 
           shape.interior(gender), missing.wings())
```

This turns the colored lines into black dashed lines.

If you want colored and dashed lines, just add the `shape.interior(gender)` function to the existing ELEMENT statement:

```
  ELEMENT: line(position(summary.percent(BT*COUNT, 
           base.aesthetic(aesthetic(aesthetic.color.interior)))), 
           color.interior(gender), shape.interior(gender), missing.wings())
```

Comment: In case it isn't clear, using the template and setting the styles directly in the GPL are alternatives: do one or the other.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But how could I remove the GPL style settings in the above example?

Answer (score 0):

I thought the point was to add these settings.  But if you don't want them, just delete the aesthetic, color, and shape function references.

Comment: I already tried this but I didn't find a working solution. The `base.aesthetic` function seems to need an aesthetic type. Syntax Reference sais: "base.aesthetic(aesthetic(aesthetic.<aesthetic type>))". And without the base function I don't get two separated lines for each category of the indipendend variable (gender). Am I missing something?